# how to find first non zero element in a column and realte it with an element of another column in Ms Excel?

Tags: excel

I have a matrix with two columns in excel datasheet.
The first column is a date and the second is a numerical value.
I want to find the first non zero element of column 2 and as an output the relevant value of column 1.

```
 A        B
0.0    12/5/2014
0.0    12/8/2014
1.3    12/12/2014
0.0    12/14/2014
```

the answer should be : 12/12/2014

Comment: column A is column 2 column B is column 1 ... find the first non zero value of column A and give me the date (column B) i.e. 1.3 and 12/12/2014

Answer (score 0):

Enter with **CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER** and adjust the ranges as necessary:

```
=INDEX(B2:B5,MATCH("",T(1/A1:A5),0))
```

(Out of the XORLX playbook):

Comment: if columns were opposite ? i.e. column A date and column B the value ?

Comment: You can just change the ranges. B2:B5 to A2:A5, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For a standard (non-array) formula,

```
=INDEX(B:B, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$999)/(A$1:A$999>0), 1))
```

It will return a raw number like 41,985. Format as a date for 12/12/2014.

Comment: I've been proselytizing the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) lately since it isn't in most people's 'favorite functions' list and can do so much more than simple pseudo-MINIF()s.

Comment: what if the columns were opposite, i.e. column A is the date and column B the values. I tried your formula but the answer is 1/0/1900 (Ms  Excel 2010). Also, what if i have more than one data columns. Should the formula posed on the top of date column ?

Comment: re: *'what if the columns were opposite... ?'* Not only is this is a pretty rudimentary question, you have already asked it before in the other answer. If you cannot figure out how to swap columns A and B in the formula, I would humbly suggest an Excel course for beginners. On the other hand, if you have more than one data column, then either edit your question to reflect the new conditions (which render these answers obsolete btw) or ask a new question.

Comment: yes, i have more than one data columns, the dates are in column A, data in columns C, D, E, ... the suggested formula does not work if dates are first, rearrange columns A - B and check yourself ... anyway thank you for your response